# linkbutton onclick event not firing in asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is a repeated question however, it seems a different situation.
I have a link button on my aspx page whose event `protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is not firing

```
 <form>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" causesvalidation="false"><a href="Product.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ItemCode") %>">LinkButton</a></asp:LinkButton>
 </form>
```

Here `<asp:LinkButton` has a green underline stating `Element 'asp:LinkButton' is missing required attribute 'runat'`
When I put runat="Server"  it gives me error that:

> Control 'Repeater1_LinkButton1_0' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

And when I put `<Form runat="Server">` it gives me

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

I am not sure if that is creating an issue. Please help

Comment: Probably you have one <form runat="server"> already defined in your aspx page or in master page.

Comment: I dont have a master page, and I looked for <form runat="server"> but its no where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question from comments.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="yourCommand" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("itemID")%>'>Click here</asp:LinkButton>
```

And in your code-behind:

```
protected void yourCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int myID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If I use runat="Server" it gives same error `Control 'Repeater1_LinkButton1_0' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

`

Comment: Sorted the error but again its not firing `LinkButton1_Command`

Comment: I solved it by placng `<form id="form1" runat="server">` just below the Body Tag, and used your method to get data all woking fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May i know Why you are putting a reference tag (href)inside the link button tag.
I think this is not right,
 try this,

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" runat="server" causesvalidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I have this href for query string , so that i can save clicked item in cookies

Comment: how would I get the itemID ?